# How to show data in QML json request

Tags: json, listview, model, qml, httprequest

So bear with me. How to create a model based on json? What is delegate? 
Is below logic is correct?

```
Model -> delegate -> json request -> json get -> show to list view
```

In below code I can not see any data on screen. How to show data in QML json request?

thanks

**UPDATED WORKING CODE:**

```
import VPlayApps 1.0
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import "qrc:/"

Item {
    id: item1
     anchors.fill: parent


    ListModel {
        id: ***modelListIP***
    }

    ListView {
        id: listview
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ***modelListIP***
        delegate: Text {
            text: listdata
        }
    }

    function getData() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "https://api.ipify.org?format=json";

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function myFunction(response) {
        var objValue = JSON.parse(response);
            ***modelListIP.append( {"listdata": objValue.ip })***
    }

    Button {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        width: parent.width
        text: "Get Data"
        onClicked: getData()
    }
}
```

This tested on Qt5.9.2 using QML app project.

Comment: You can explain how you want to see the view. So far the description of your problem is confusing and does not contribute anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is totally wrong.

1. `JSON.parse()` returns `Object`, not array. So you cannot call length() on it. Remember - `{}` - object, `[]` - array.
2. Your request returns something like `{"ip":"111.111.111.111"}`. Where do you see `Name` here? So you should append items `model.append( {"listdata": arr.ip })`, not like you do it now. Don't forget to surround the parameter name with quotes.
3. `listview.model.append` shoud be replaced with `model.append`. Learn what is `Occam's razor`.
4. `model` is not good id for item. Using reserved words is a bad style.

So I advice you to read documentation twice when you facing such problems.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to QML and the Model View delagate as well as js in qml very new to me. I updated my code and now is working. I should read and study more about model and delegate. Kind Regards