# How to use QML Model, Delegate, Repeater, View?

Tags: qt, model, delegates, qml, repeater

I have json result as shown below. In my QML project I want to parse the json which I did help of [How to show data in QML json request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748402/how-to-show-data-in-qml-json-request) . Now I want to set 4 flag. Local flag, USA, UK and Europe in one row. And I will add as shown below.

My question is how to use QML Model, Delegate, Repeater, View? And which view is beter solution to have?

```
{ "tarih": "20171212", 
        "currency": { 
                "usa": { "buy": "3,7900", "sell": "3,8800", "e_buy": "3,7900" }, 
                "stg": { "buy": "5,0700", "sell": "5,1650", "e_buy": "5,0700" }, 
                "eur": { "buy": "4,4700", "sell": "4,5600", "e_buy": "4,4700" } 
                } 
}
```

[image]

thank you

UPDATE:

Easiest way to do it is this:
Parse json with;

```
(var result = JSON.parse(request.responseText))
```

And I get items with this:

```
(getUsaBuy.text = result.currency.usa.buy)
```

Comment: What is the difference between this question and the previous one?!!!!

Comment: All you need is [here](https://qmlbook.github.io/en/ch06/index.html)

Comment: @eyllanesc previos one about parsing the json. With that answer I learn about QML Model, Delegate, Repeater and View.I know there are lost of information in net. In here I am asking to understand and practice how to use qml model, delegate etc. I might get different kind of json and I don't want myself to become ailen each time when I see qml & json. I am trying to learn with step by step.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: There is no generic answer since it will depend on the data and the view.

Comment: @folibis I look at that link before and I get confuse. it mix lots of layout as well. I have a example json in my question and I need some one to provide a small qml example using model and delegate with information that I can understand bit more clearly. Coming from Qt C++i QML and ui are very new concept for me.

Comment: @eyllanesc can you provide me a small example so I can mark as an answer. And please can you add small description in your example about model, delegate etc.

Comment: @eyllanesc nothing at the moment. Because I didn't understand whole logic.

Comment: First I want to see what you have tried, we are not a free coding service, you must know the rules of [ask].

Comment: @eyllanesc I will update my question than

Comment: @eyllanesc I discover something else. Using (var result = JSON.parse(request.responseText)) and using (getUsaBuy.text = result.currency.usa.buy) become much easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

I motife my original post from [How to show data in QML json request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748402/how-to-show-data-in-qml-json-request).

**Running Code:**

```
if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (request.status && request.status === 200) {
        var result = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
        // BUY
        textSTG_BUY.text = **result.currency.stg.buy**

        // SELL
        textSTG_SELL.text = **result.currency.stg.sell**

    }
    else {
        console.log("Log:", request.status, request.statusText)
    }
}
```